# Connect to hidden wireless network on nmtui

Tags: fedora, tty, networkmanager, nmcli, wpa2

I'm running fish shell on TTY in Fedora.

I have nmtui (Network Manager with text user interface) installed.
I can activate connections.
I want to connect to a hidden wireless network with WPA2 security whose credentials I know.
Suggestions on nmcli as well as other ways (terminal commands, config) to do that is very much welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I used the following workaround: Add your hidden wifi via nmtui ('Edit connections') and activate it by `nmcli con up HIDDEN_WIFI_PROFILE_NAME`. After this, it should be in the wifi list of nmtui.